# error while using git command in cmd

Tags: git

i used to have git installed but for some reason an update got rid of it, i tried to reinstal my git and afterwards i get this error while trying to clone, push,... (also get same error when trying to push in visual studio) do any of you know how to fix this?

```
c:\wamp\www\x.y>git clone https://github.com/mjoris/ws1-sws-course-materials
Cloning into 'ws1-sws-course-materials'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/mjoris/ws1-sws-course-materials/': error setting certificate verify locations:
CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
CApath: none
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting your system sslCAInfo using backslashes like this:

```
git config --system http.sslcainfo "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an SSL Verification issue. If you are using mysisGit, 
[this link](http://blog.vogella.com/2010/08/09/git-https/) shows how to disable it.

**EDIT**

I'm glad you found a solution. In case others have the same issue, here are some other things to try.

If you are trying to a server without proper certificates, you can set `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true` each time you run a command:

`GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git clone https://url`

Or you could disable ssl verification. For a single repo, make sure your are in the repo you want and run:

`git config http.sslVerify "false"`.

Or you can disable it for all repos using:

`git config --global http.sslverify "false"`

Which is what worked for me. Alternatively, you can see if changing the CAPATH fixes it. For windows, the sslcainfo could be using the wrong slashes (like in @c-rish's answer):

`git config --system http.sslcainfo "C:\<path>\<to>\<your>\.crt file"`

Comment: yes i found a sollution, i simply looked what my past git version was, deleted the version i had and put the old version back, now it works, thanks for the information